# Dynamic controls and sliding panels/rollouts in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface

Is it easy to do sliding panels, such as the one show in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbVIu61fQcA&feature=related), where the controls are populated dynamically but also expanded/collapsed when the user is clicking the panels. It also allows scrolling if the height of the visible panels is larger than the application height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

To answer your next question, the sliding panels are used in your XAML just like any other panel. For some example controls, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485232/is-there-a-wpf-control-i-can-use-to-expand-collapse-panels-animated)