# Menu and update to the main pane (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, menu

I am trying to build a project where Menu is to the left of the screen (eg. Tree view in Outlook). And when I click on individual items in the tree view on the left the main pane updates (Similar to Outlook).

Can anyone provide some sample code or links to sample code that I can use as reference? I am sorry if this is ambiguous. Any help would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485232/is-there-a-wpf-control-i-can-use-to-expand-collapse-panels-animated

Comment: I don't see how that question relates to this one.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, this just comes down to databinding -- binding the contents of the main pane to the selected item in your menu.

An example is demonstrated in this SilverlightTV episode, which does it in Blend with zero code required (but you must have Expression Blend, of course): http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/SilverlightTV/Silverlight-TV-12-The-Best-Blend-3-Video-Ever/