# WPF Accordion control within a popup

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface, accordion

I'm using an Accordion control as per this link - [Is there a WPF control I can use to expand/collapse panels (animated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485232/is-there-a-wpf-control-i-can-use-to-expand-collapse-panels-animated)

The problem is that I'd like this control to be hosted by a Popup. Problem is that the Popup does not get resized when I expand any of the groups. If I give the popup a fixed size, then the items get expanded, but it's an ugly effect, because the first time you see a large popup with a few collapsed items on top. Would rather have the popup resizing as the items expand and/or collapse.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

EDIT: Looks like I totally got it wrong. I didn't need to use the Accordion control. Have just put the expanders within a grid, giving each row Height="Auto". The popup resizes nicely when expanding/collapsing the groups.

Answer (score 0):

I really hate WPF's default Popup, so usually use my own. The code for it can be found [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/)

The default size of the Popup Content is based on the size of the content inside the popup. Here's a rough example of how it can be used:

```
<local:PopupPanel
    local:PopupPanel.PopupParent="{Binding ElementName=PopupParentPanel}"
    local:PopupPanel.IsPopupVisible="{Binding IsPopupVisible}">

    <DockPanel>
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="Silver" Content="Popup Header" />
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Save" />
        <local:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding }" />
    </DockPanel>

</local:PopupPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set height of the popup using binding to the ActualHeihgt property of your accordion control.

It will look like that:

```
<Popup Height="{Binding ElementName=myAccordion,Path=ActualHeight" >
 <Accordion x:Name="myAccordion">
  ...
 </Accordion>
</Popup>
```

But you'll definitely to set a height limit. Could be solved using converter with parameter.